# How did prophets know when God will speak to them, to separate from their wives?

Tags: nevua-prophecy, behaalotcha-parsha, aharon

[Rashi on Numbers 12:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.12.4?lang=bi) comments in explanation of the word פִּתְאֹ֗ם (suddenly) that Aharon and Miriam were shouting for water to purify themselves because God had revealed Himself to them suddenly.

So how was it other times that God spoke to Aaron or other prophets, did he send an owl to notify them?

Comment: Maybe He only spoke to them when they were pure.

Comment: The Navi has to put himself into the proper frame of mind in order to see prophecy so they only did that when they were pure. This time Hashem came to them to show them that Moshe was different and he has to always be ready.

Comment: I always wondered how that incident played out in real time. If Hashem is talking to you, can you just put Him on hold while you race to find water? Was there a sort of door knock before the conversation started?

Comment: @Shmuel r u the one who edited it?

Comment: @Shmuel the edited question kind of answered it for me.

Comment: @Shmuel so why did you ask me about it? Where did you see the deleted question?

Comment: @Shmuel no, this is the only question about this issue that i posted. Someone did edit this question as well, so maybe that's what you're noticing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question seems to take for granted that prophecy was typically achieved in an unprepared unsolicited state. However quite the contrary is true.

Prophecy entails a process of physical and spiritual preparation (as @Dude points out much of this is explained in Ch. 7 of H. Yesode ha-Torah). Typically in order for prophecy to devolve upon an individual prophet, they must have already been prepared for the prophetic state. Generally however, prophets led otherwise "normal" lives, participated in family life, had wives with whom they co-habited, etc. When a given prophet wanted to place themselves in a state such that they would be ready to receive prophecy, they would among other things, temporarily separate themselves from their wives.

The Rambam writes H. Yesode ha-Torah 7:6:

> כל הנביאים אין מתנבאים בכל עת שירצו משה רבינו אינו כן אלא כל זמן
> שיחפוץ רוח הקודש לובשתו ונבואה שורה עליו ואינו צריך לכוין דעתו ולהזדמן
> לה שהרי הוא מכוון ומזומן ועומד כמלאכי השרת. לפיכך מתנבא בכל עת שנאמר
> עמדו ואשמעה מה יצוה ה' לכם. ובזה הבטיחו האל שנאמר לך אמור להם שובו לכם
> לאהליכם ואתה פה עמוד עמדי. הא למדת שכל הנביאים כשהנבואה מסתלקת מהם
> חוזרים לאהלם שהוא צרכי הגוף כלם כשאר העם. לפיכך אין פורשין מנשותיהם.
> ומשה רבינו לא חזר לאהלו הראשון לפיכך פירש מן האשה לעולם ומן הדומה לו
> ונקשרה דעתו לצור העולמים ולא נסתלק מעליו ההוד לעולם וקרן עור פניו
> ונתקדש כמלאכים
>
> All the [other] prophets cannot prophesy whenever they desire. Moses,
> our teacher, was different. Whenever he desired, the holy spirit would
> envelop him, and prophecy would rest upon him. He did not have to
> concentrate his attention to prepare himself [for prophecy], because
> his [mind] was always concentrated, prepared, and ready [to appreciate
> spiritual truth] as the angels [are]. Therefore, he would prophesy at
> all times, as [Numbers 9:8] states: "Stand and hear what God will
> command you." He was promised this by God, as [implied by Deuteronomy
> 5:27-28]: "Go and tell them: `Return to your tents,' but you stand
> here together with Me." This should be interpreted to mean: When
> prophecy departs from all the [other] prophets, they return to their
> "tents" - i.e., the needs of the body like other people. Therefore,
> they do not separate themselves from their wives. Moses, our teacher,
> never returned to his original "tent." Therefore, he separated himself
> from women and everything of that nature forever. He bound his mind to
> the Eternal Rock. [Accordingly,] the glory never left him forever. The
> flesh of his countenance shone, [for] he became holy like the angels.

Moshe Rabbenu however, permanently separated himself from his wife as an aspect of rendering himself constantly prepared for prophetic engagement. This was not something God commanded Moshe to do, it was something he elected to do ([Shabboth 87a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.87a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) teaches it is one of three actions he took of his own reasoning that God agreed to).

Miriam and Aharon (not knowing/understanding) that this permanent separation from his wife was uniquely proper for Moshe, were critical of this act (see [Rashi Numbers 12:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Numbers.12.1.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). Accordingly when prophecy suddenly (פִּתְאֹ֗ם) devolved upon them they were surprised, as they had not undergone their regular preparations which normally would have included separating themselves from their spouses. It was then that they experientially understood that they had erred in criticizing Moshe for his action of separating from his wife. Unlike other prophets, Moshe was subject to the prophetic state at any given moment and thus his separation was proper.

Answer (score 1):

Yesodei haTorah - Chapter Seven describes that prophecy was a process that led up to the prophecy and not sudden except for Moshe rabenu who was always ready for prophecy. It seems to me then that this was an exception to the general rule and as a result they were caught off guard and had to rush to get ready.

Answer (score 1):

As @Shmosel [said](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135374/how-did-prophets-know-when-god-will-speak-to-them-to-seperate-from-their-wives#) in the comment-section, G-d called to Moshe, since he was "fit" to receive the call. Aharon and Miriam were not, since they were impure at that moment and needed to purify themselves. Moshe on the otherhand was always pure.

> אל משה, to Moses, etc. The reason that G'd called to Moses when it was Aaron and Miriam He wanted to speak to is that the latter were ritually impure at the time and first had to purify themselves. He called to Moses in order to give recognition to the fact that Moses kept himself pure at all times by the very fact that he did not indulge in marital relations with his wife. This is why he was able to be called upon by G'd without having to undergo any preparation. This fact contrasted with the state of Miriam and Aaron [(Or HaChaim, Bamidbar 12:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.12.4?lang=bi&with=Or%20HaChaim&lang2=en)